# F# fsautocomplete on mono targeting .NET Standard in emacs fsharp-mode

Tags: .net, .net-core, emacs, f#, mono

I am trying to set up my dev environment consistently across environments. My current issue is getting auto-complete set up.

Is there any way to configure fsautocomplete in Emacs fsharp-mode to do intellisense and completion against .NET Standard Libraries?

This seems to be specific to scripts, but I intend to have a fair number of scripts, so it is relevant.

I am using:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- emacs 25.2
- dotnet-sdk 2.2 (following directions [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/hello-world-tutorial/install) for Linux -> Ubuntu 18.04)
- Mono 6.0 (following directions [here](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-ubuntu) for Ubuntu 18.04)

I have configured `(setq inferior-fsharp-program "dotnet fsi")` to use the F# interpreter packaged with dotnet core.

Where I'm struggling is getting fsautocomplete to work with .NET Standard libraries. To be clear, fsautocomplete is working just fine in general, but not when I use a .NET Standard library. Two examples below.

I configure my workspace with:

```sh
$ paket init
$ paket add FSharp.Data
$ paket restore
```

Now I write a simple script. Note the first is targeting .NET Framework 4.5 (`net45` when reading the lib)

```ml
#r "packages/FSharp.Data/lib/net45/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data

type Species = HtmlProvider<"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_world's_100_most_threatened_species">

let species = [ for x in Species.GetSample().Tables.``Species list``.Rows ->
                x.Type, x.``Common name`` ]
```

Here is the version targeting .NET Standard 2.0:

```
#r "packages/FSharp.Data/lib/netstandard2.0/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data

type Species = HtmlProvider<"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_world's_100_most_threatened_species">

let species = [ for x in Species.GetSample().Tables.``Species list``.Rows ->
                x.Type, x.``Common name`` ]
```

The first version (.NET Framework 4.5) gives auto-completion just fine and no intellisense errors.

The second version (.NET Standard 2.0) does not work with auto-completion and throws intellisense errors. The text of the error message is below and a screengrab is at the bottom of this post.

> A reference to the type 'FSharp.Data.HtmlProvider,Sample="" in assembly 'FSharp.Data' was found, but the type could not be found in that assembly.

Now, I evaluate the script in the interpreter with either version of the library and it runs just fine. But I will be targeting .NET Standard and building with the .NET Core sdk build tools. As it stands, my best workaround is just use .NET Framework library references while writing scripts, but testing them against .NET Standard, which seems un-ideal.

I have searched for config options in the following places:

- [FSAutoComplete github page](https://github.com/fsharp/FsAutoComplete)
- [fsharp-mode github page](https://github.com/fsharp/emacs-fsharp-mode)
- fsharp-mode source code
- [Mono project site](https://www.mono-project.com/)
- Various searches, including for all of the above and also referring to the VSCode Ionide extension

So far, I'm not finding anything that seems to let me configure this. Any thoughts?

[image: intellisense error]

Comment: I would recommend using VS Code rather than emac for F# development. Since it is also cross-platform and has various plugins for F#

Comment: It's an option I've considered, but I find it fairly clunky compared to emacs. I did try digging into the Ionide extension to see how they handle switching between 'net' and 'netcore' for the FSAC executable. It's a configurable setting, but I wasn't able to find what that actually means in terms of how it calls FSAC.

Comment: Try using a dotnet core 3.0 preview (see here for some relevant info: https://vxlabs.com/2019/04/16/dotnet-fsi-in-vscode/). I don't know the specifics but I've tended to use fsharpi with mono previously and it's only recently that dotnet fsi has worked for me (vscode, vim).

Comment: @drkmtr Yeah, I've seen thhat, but I've not been able to figure out how to invoke the FSAutoComplete binary with dotnet core. From an emacs perspective, I should just need the command to execute FSAC, but I can't figure out how to invoke it in dotnet core.